# Upgrade Teamcity from version 4 to 6 without losing build history

Tags: teamcity

Does anyone have experience of upgrading Teamcity server from version 4 to version 6 without losing all the build history?

Since I am not able to run a direct upgrade on our existing Teamcity server (version 4.5.4), my plan was to install a latest Teamcity server to another host and trying to import the data that somehow exported from the old Teamcity server.

After reading both documentation for [version 4](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD4/TeamCity+Data+Backup) and [version 6](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/Upgrade), I am not sure how to proceed. Does anyone have any suggestion on this? Thanks.

Comment: You could make a clone for training with direct upgrade. It's also possible that upgrade would go better if splitted: 4 -> 5 and then 5 -> 6.

Comment: I thought about making a clone also. however, that requires another licence for version 4 according to this [link](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD65/How+To...#HowTo...-CreateacopyofTeamCityserverwithalldata), under title "Licensing issues". We have around 100 build configurations and need a enterprise licence to run Teamcity. JetBrains suggested in the link to request an evaluation licence, however, they don't provide evaluation licence for version 4 anymore.

Comment: And 4-> 5 and 5->6 will probably encounter similar licencing issue. But thanks away.

Comment: "You cannot use a single TeamCity license on two running servers at the same time" but you could try clone upgrade in planned nightly downtime of the main server. Also I guess that free professional edition (available since version 3) would handle upgrade the same way as enterprise one. Furthermore I believe it's possible to arrange this licensing issue with sales department in a nice way.

Comment: Thanks Vadzim, I already got one from JetBrains support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forgot to circle back to this question after it was solved. Recently I have again migrated and updated out Teamcity installation from version 6.5 to 7.1.4 without losing any history or data, so I think I'd better share what I did.

Basically what I did were:

1. Shutdown old version 4 Teamcity installation.
2. Dump the database used by teamcity to a `.sql` file. In my case, we uses MySQL, so I used something like: `mysqldump -u User -pPassword teamcity_db_name > teamcity.sql`
3. On the new server, use `rsync` to copy the `.BuildServer` folder from the old version 4 Teamcity server.
4. On the new server, create db user and database in MySQL with same names as in the old server.
5. Import the `.sql` dump: `mysql -u User -pPassword teamcity_db_name < teamcity.sql`
6. Unzip the new Teamcity `.tar.gz` distribution file to a location, say `/home/teamcity/Teamcity`
7. Run `/home/teamcity/Teamcity/bin/teamcity-server.sh start`
8. Open `http://<your new teamcity server>:8111/` and it will ask to enter maintenance mode by finding a **secret token** in `teamcity-server.log` in `/home/teamcity/Teamcity/logs/` folder.
9. After entering the token, it asks to confirm the upgrade. This step besically upgrade the format of your `.BuildServer` folder.
10. Wait sometime, for me it took around 30 mins to do the upgrade.
11. Almost done, but don't forget to update build agent so that they know where the new teamcity server is.

It went extremely well for me both for version 4 -> 6 upgrade and version 6 -> 7 upgrade.